# spl_autoload_register trouble loading PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, php-5.3

My `spl_autoload_register` works very well but I get into a trouble when try to load PDO o mysqli

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {

    require( "{$class_name}.php" );

});
```

Getting this warning:

```
Warning: require(aplicacion\dao\mysqli.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I believe the solution maybe something like if class or file doesn't exists then "BREAK", something like: IGNORE THIS SPL_AUTOLOAD continue normal loading.

Comment: Do you use namespace? If yes, instantiating PDO inside your namespace should be like `new \PDO;`, note the backslash. Or you can add `use PDO;` into the file that is using PDO.

Answer (score 1):

Your autoloader is the first to act for any unknown class. So you need to make sure, you get others the chance to act behind it.

You are requiring a file for any class, and you are not providing a pdo.php. So this fails.

Try this instead:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    $file = $class_name.'.php';
    if (file_exists($file) {
        require($file);
    }
});
```